# http cache-control and authentication

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, authentication, caching, http-caching

I would like to aks if anyone been solving Client(browser) side caching of authenticated content?

Task:

- cache the CONTENT for non-authenticated users
- cache the CONTENT for authenticated users

There is a challenge here as you want to make sure that those calls are not shared between different authenticated users / non-authenticated users.

I read something that http header `Vary: Authenticated` can be used, but I haven't seen any good example or explanation.